# System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method

Tags: apex, batch

i write below trigger on that time this error is appear plz help me

```
trigger GK_betaObject_trg on GIRI2__betaObject__c(after insert,after delete,after update) { 
   List<Rollup_Config__c> sfRollup = [Select Id,Parent_Field_Name__c,Parent_Object_Name__c,
 Parent_Relation_Name__c,Child_Field_Name__c , 
          Child_Object_Name__c ,Operation_Type__c,Filter1__c,Filter2__c,
   Filter3__c,Filter4__c,Filter5__c from Rollup_Config__c where Child_Object_Name__c ='GIRI2__betaObject__c' ]; 
   if(sfRollup.size() > 0){ 
     for(Rollup_Config__c conf: sfRollup){ 
         List<Id> pIds = new List<Id>(); 
         List<sobject> dataList = Trigger.IsDelete ?  Trigger.old :Trigger.new; 
         for(sobject rec :  dataList){ 
            pIds.add(String.valueOf(rec.get(conf.Parent_Relation_Name__c))); 
         } 
         if(pIds!=null && pIds.size() > 0){ 
             System.Debug('pIds : '+pIds); 
             LookUpConfigBatch batchObj = new LookUpConfigBatch(conf); 
             batchObj.pIds = pIds; 
             String batchId = Database.executeBatch(batchObj); 
         } 
     } 
 } 
}
```

Comment: what is the API version of your batch class

Comment: 33 version Himanshu...

Comment: go to your Apex Class detail page you will see five tabs
 
Class Body,
Class Summary,
Version Settings,
Log Filters

click on version settings tab

Comment: then it seems that your code is running another batch or updating some other records from same object. You have written your batch call which is not a good practice this issue is coming. you should rectify your code and move batch code outside the trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Some batch or future process is updating records which is causing this to attempt to execute another batch and you cannot do that.

To Stop the error:

```
if(pIds!=null && pIds.size() > 0 && !system.isFuture() && !system.isBatch()){ 
             System.Debug('pIds : '+pIds); 
             LookUpConfigBatch batchObj = new LookUpConfigBatch(conf); 
             batchObj.pIds = pIds; 
             String batchId = Database.executeBatch(batchObj); 
         }
```

Then rerun all your test methods to ensure it did not stop any business logic from happening. If you do not have good test methods you will need to inspect your code / logic to ensure that all updates are happening as expected.

Comment: First error: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0328000003I20KAAS; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, GIRI2.GK_betaObject_trg: execution of AfterUpdate

caused by: System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be cal

Comment: deploy after run the process i get that error above

Comment: Then either you did not make the changes I made or it is not coming from that piece of code.....

Comment: then how to rectify that error....

Comment: You will have to do some debugging. Without seeing your code for the entire transaction it is hard to say. Simply, you CANNOT fire off another batch during a transaction started from the start or execute method.

Comment: @user25465 - no it is not, it is the trigger that you posted not a batch

Comment: You are going to have to do some work debugging to find the root cause as it is no longer coming from the code snippets I fixed.

Comment: @user25465 the code in the comments appears to be incomplete. You'll need to post the rest so we can update the question. Unless you've resolved the problem?